# Do the normal numbers have Lebesgue measure 1?

Tags: probability, lebesgue-measure, normal-number

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824147/do-the-normal-numbers-form-a-borel-set) I found out that the normal numbers in $[0,1]$ form a Borel set. Since every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable, I now wonder what would be the Lebesgue measure of the set of normal numbers?

Intuitively, normal numbers are what you would 'expect' to get when you pick a 'random number' in $[0,1]$. Therefore, I suspect that almost all numbers are normal. Then the Lebesgue measure would be 1.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415069/how-to-show-that-sets-of-normal-numbers-are-lebesgue-measurable) they prove it by using that the non-normal numbers have measure 0. However, how do you prove that?

Comment: If it helps, it should be proven in the book Inevitable Randomness in Discrete Mathematics from Beck. (it's used as the reference for that fact on wikipedia) I don't have the full version of the book, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: There is a reference to a book by Beck for this result in the Wikipedia page on [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#cite_note-FOOTNOTEBeck2009-2). I don't have the book, so I can't confirm this.

Comment: @VincentBatens: snap $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Of possibly related interest is the result stated in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647858/13130). Also, the 1994 paper [*Normal numbers and subsets of* $\mathbb N$ *with given densities*](https://eudml.org/doc/212021) and the 2014 paper [*Normal numbers and the Borel hierarchy*](https://math.berkeley.edu/~slaman/papers/pi3.pdf).

Comment: @RobArthan That was where I found my reference too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove this for simply normal numbers in base $2$. Let $a$ be a uniformly random number in $[0,1]$. Write $a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n2^{-n}$. Then the $a_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with mean $0.5$. By the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), it follows that the sample average $\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}$ converges to the expected value $0.5$ with probability $1$. With other words, the set of real numbers $x=\sum x_n2^{-n}\in[0,1]$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}=\frac12$ has Lebesgue measure $1$.

The case for higher bases can probably be proven in a similar way.

Now we can take the intersection for all bases. This is the intersection of countably many sets with measure $1$. Therefore, the interection also has measure $1$.